# Programmatically set TableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

So I am trying to create a `UITableViewCell` programatically to be used in a `UITableView`. I have everything setup, but the tableview is empty when I load the simulator. See code below:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var firstText = UILabel()
    var secondText = UILabel()
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        firstText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        secondText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        contentView.addSubview(firstText)
        contentView.addSubview(secondText)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                firstText.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
                firstText.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
                firstText.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
                firstText.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
            ])
        
    }
    

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

and then the UITableViewDataSource:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)  -> UITableViewCell {

        let person = people[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        let name = person.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String
        let age = person.value(forKeyPath: "age") as? String
    
        cell.firstText.text = name
        cell.secondText.text = age
        
        return cell


    }
```

Full ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    var names : [String] = []
    
    var people: [NSManagedObject] = []
    
    let TableView = UITableView() // view
    
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        setupComponents()
        setupTableView()
        TableView.delegate = self
        TableView.dataSource = self
        TableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        names = ["Samantha", "Jacob", "Justin"]
      }
    
    func setupComponents() {
        self.title = "Core Data"
        let addButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(addTap))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}
        let fetchRequest =  NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Person")
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
         //3
          do {
            people = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
           } catch let error as NSError {
               print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
          }
    }
    
    func setupTableView() {
        view.addSubview(TableView)
        TableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        TableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        TableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        TableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        TableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
      }
    
    @objc func addTap() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Friend", message: "Add the name of your friend", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Now", style: .default) { [unowned self] action in

            guard let textField = alert.textFields?.first, let nameToSave = textField.text else { return }
            let secondTextField = alert.textFields![1]
            let age = secondTextField.text
            let ageInt = Int(age!)
            self.save(name: nameToSave, age: ageInt!)
            self.TableView.reloadData()
          }

          let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)

          alert.addTextField()
          alert.addTextField()
          alert.addAction(saveAction)
          alert.addAction(cancelAction)
          present(alert, animated: true)
    }
    
    func save(name: String, age: Int) {

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}

        // 1
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        // 2
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Person",
                                           in: managedContext)!

        let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                         insertInto: managedContext)

        // 3
        person.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "name")
        person.setValue(age, forKeyPath: "age")

        // 4
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            people.append(person)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.userInfo)
        }
        
        print("People", people)
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return people.count
        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)  -> UITableViewCell {

        let person = people[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        let name = person.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String
        let age = person.value(forKeyPath: "age") as? String
    
        cell.firstText.text = name
        cell.secondText.text = age
        
        return cell


    }
}
```

`name` and `age` are both valid and working, returning results so its not that.

Comment: Is `awakeFromNib()` called? Could you debug the frames of the labels? Either with XCode Debug 3D Views or with old methids setting the background color of each to red/orange (a visible color)?

Comment: Can you post the code where you register the cell class with the table view?

Comment: Can you also post your table view delegate code?

Comment: @strwils I've added the full ViewController in the post now.

Comment: @Larme I changed the label's background colors to red, and still nothing appears in the table view. I'm assuming the label are not placed correctly.

Comment: You are calling `TableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")`, so you shouldn't be calling `awakeFromNib()`, put a breakpoint or a `print()` inside to verify. You should override then `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)` where you should add the subview labels. It's stated in the doc of `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614878-dequeuereusablecell

Comment: @larme thanks again, I was able to load the labels now!

Comment: Try putting your cell's layout code inside a `configureViews` function, and then add two initializers, an override init(frame:), and a required init(coder:), in both bodies, call the super.init that corresponds, and call your configureViews function, that may be the problem.